# Page Event is not saving into xDB

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I want to save some information about that page that has been clicked by the user so I register a page event on `processItem` pipeline for this I did below code:

```
  public class RegisterCustomPageEvents : ProcessItemProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(ProcessItemArgs args)
        {

            foreach (TrackingField trackingParameter in (IEnumerable<TrackingField>)args.TrackingParameters)
                TrackingFieldProcessor.ProcessEvents(args.Interaction, trackingParameter);

            if (!Tracker.Enabled || Tracker.Current == null || !Tracker.Current.IsActive)
            {
                return;
            }

            FireCustomEvent(args);
        }

        private void FireCustomEvent(ProcessItemArgs args)
        {
            var myPageTemplateId = "{ED0B99D5-4992-429F-84FE-F8F3D902CAB5}";

            if (args.Item == null || Context.Item.TemplateID.ToString() != myPageTemplateId)
            {
                return;
            }
            var ev = Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents[Guid.Parse("{059A1829-DD32-47B6-8EA6-BEEFAC98DC6E}")];

            if (ev != null)
            {
                var pageData = new PageEventData(ev.Alias, ev.Id);

                pageData.Text = "Event";

                var fullUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

                pageData.CustomValues.Add("Url", fullUrl);
                pageData.CustomValues.Add("PageTemplateId", args.Item.TemplateID.ToString());
                pageData.CustomValues.Add("ItemVersion", args.Item.Version.Number);

                pageData.ItemId = args.Item.ID.ToGuid();

                try
                {
                    Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(pageData);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error("Unable to fire custom event", ex, this);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <processItem>
                <processor type="XXX.RegisterCustomPageEvents, XXX" />
            </processItem>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

My issue is that I am not able to see page events in `Interactions` table. I tried to abandon the session.

Comment: Can you confirm you are testing and abandoning session on CD or Standalone role?

Comment: It is on standalone

Comment: Has the page event with ID "059A1829-DD32-47B6-8EA6-BEEFAC98DC6E" definitely been deployed to ref data DB?

Comment: @DeanOBrien Yes it is deployed

Comment: Did you get this working? I tried using the exact same code and could see the pageEvent registered in the interactions table. However, the customValues were missing. Looking into this further, it seems you must create a custom event to store your additional info and add a converter.

Comment: Added my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the below lines in the Sitecore document:

[image]

To achieve this, I followed below link:

https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/storing-full-urls-in-page-view-events